# Rails - Multiple instances of the same model in the same form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I'm having trouble creating a form with multiple instances of the same model. My form is for a timesheet application. Below is a screenshot of what I would like to create.
http://imageshack.us/f/541/5w3o.png/

The table that will store the data is called project_activity and contains the following column names:
activity_id PK, project_id, task_id, party_id, activity_hours.

Below is my code. The screenshot I provided is the output from my code however, it fails to save any records in the back end.

My intention is to have 3 drop down menus (party, project and task) which when selected by the user will be stored in a local variable. This variable will then be captured in a hidden field tag for each activity_hour field displayed so that when the form is saved, 7 project_activity records will be created with the same party, project and task.

I haven't attempted this in the code provided because I don't know how to. Is it possible?

```
<h1>Timesheet</h1>

<%= form_for(@project_activity) do |f| %>

    <%= f.collection_select(:party_id, Party.all, :id, :party_name, {:prompt => params[current_party]}, {class: "span2"}) %></br>

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td><%= select_tag  "project_activity[project_id]", 
                        grouped_options_for_select(Project.for_select(@date.strftime("%Y%m%d"))), 
                        {include_blank: true, class: "span2"} %></td>
            <td><%= select_tag  "project_activity[task_id]", 
                            grouped_options_for_select(ProjectTask.for_select(@date.strftime("%Y%m%d"))), 
                        {include_blank: true, class: "span2"} %></td>

            <% form_date = @date.beginning_of_week %>
            <%= (@date.beginning_of_week..@date.end_of_week).each do %>
                <%= f.fields_for(@project_activity) do |builder| %>
                    <td>
                        <%= builder.number_field :activity_hours, :class => 'input-mini' %>
                        <%= hidden_field_tag "project_activity[activity_date]", form_date %>
                        <% form_date+=1 %>
                    </td>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>

        <tr>
            <td><%= f.submit "Save", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <% end %>
```

Comment: Could you post your models (their fields and associations)?

Comment: Thanks for replying Jonathan. I have updated my question with further information. 
A party has many project_activities, a project_activity has one party
A project_task has many project_activities,a project_activity has one project_task
A project_task has one project, a project has many project_tasks.

Project_activity is the only table storing information from this form. The column names are,
activity_id PK, project_id, task_id, party_id, activity_hours.
Thanks again for your help.